# build a tree object using mongo aggregate pipeline from flat list of documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given a flat dummy list of items:

```
const TreeNodeModel = model(
      'flatten_tree',
      new Schema({
        expressID: Number,
        name: String,
        children: [Number], // children express Ids
      }),
    );

    // Root
    await new TreeNodeModel({ name: 'root', children: [1, 2, 3] }).save();

    // Subs
    await new TreeNodeModel({ name: 'sub1', expressID: 1, children: [4] }).save();
    await new TreeNodeModel({ name: 'sub2', expressID: 2, children: [] }).save();
    await new TreeNodeModel({ name: 'sub3', expressID: 3, children: [] }).save();

    // sub Subs
    await new TreeNodeModel({ name: 'subSub4', expressID: 4, children: [] }).save();
```

I would like to recursivly build the tree structure based on expressID/children relationship of the items.

I have currently this aggregation pipeline which is not recursive:

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'name': 'root'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$children'
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'flatten_trees', 
      'localField': 'children', 
      'foreignField': 'expressID', 
      'as': 'children2'
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$_id', 
      'children': {
        '$push': {
          '$first': '$children2'
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

with this kind of result:

```
{
    name: 'root'
    children:
    [
        {
            expressID: 1,
            name: 'sub1',
            children: [4], // Not populated...
        },
        {
            expressID: 2,
            name: 'sub2',
            children: [],
        },
        {
            expressID: 3,
            name: 'sub3',
            children: [],
        }]
}
```

... which is almost great, but as you can see, only the first level of children is populated with corresponding documents.

Is there a way with aggregation pipeline to perform this recursively ?